# Laravel decode array request

Tags: php, laravel

I have problems with Laravel decoding base64 array from request.
Idea is that frontend is sending base64 encoded properties, and backend should get those values and decode them.

So the request looks like:

```
description[en]: some_base64_encripted_data
description[fr]: some_base64_encripted_data
description[nl]: some_base64_encripted_data
```

As you see, description is passed as array and should stay that way. But how can I decode those values in the Laravel backend?
So the request validation looks like:

```
'description' => ['max:' . $count_languages, new ValidateArrayKeys($languages_keys)],
'description.*' => ['string', 'min:1'],
```

and it works fine. But I have to change those properties before they are received by the controller.
So I'm trying different ways to change them in function withValidator, something like this:

```
$description_en = base64_decode($this->input('description')['en']);
$description_fr = base64_decode($this->input('description')['fr']);
$description_nl = base64_decode($this->input('description')['nl']);

$this["description['en']"] = $description_en;
$this["description['fr']"] = $description_fr;
$this["description['nl']"] = $description_nl;

$this['description[en]'] = $description_en;
$this['description[fr]'] = $description_fr;
```

But it's not decoding anything. Any ideas what could I do?

Comment: What do you mean with "it is not decoding anything"? how do you know that? Show what you finally end up with...

Comment: Just use a custom cast on the attribute. Documentation shows an example with json casting, should be trivial for you to change it to base64. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#custom-casts

Comment: I tried with cast but no success

Comment: base64 encoding is NOT the same as encrypting data if you encode you're data in your frontend for 'safety' then the simplest solution is to just remove the encoding as everybody can decode a base64 string.

Comment: I know that, but frontend should decode it. We are using sentia and aws, so we have restrictions in sending HTML data.

Comment: If you tried a cast class with no success, show that effort here

Answer (score 0):

You can use a middleware to do it, like how laravel uses `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull` to ... convert empty strings to null in the requests.

```
<?php

namespace Where\You\Want\It;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest;

class ConvertBase64Strings extends TransformsRequest
{
    /**
     * Transform the given value.
     *
     * @param  string  $key
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function transform($key, $value)
    {
        return is_string($value) ? base64_decode($value) : $value;
    }
}
```

You can adjust the global condition (other that the input being a string) and add the middleware where needed.

If you want it to be enabled everywhere, add it to `App\Http\kernel.php` in  `protected $middleware`

```
/**
 * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
 *
 * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
 *
 * @var array
*/
protected $middleware = [
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    //...
    \Where\You\Want\It\ConvertBase64Strings::class,
];
```